# get the Id from a item grid and save into a variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I'm working with Laravel 5 to do the following: I have a grid that shows all the clients that the company has, in each row of that grid, there is a button to select that client like this:

[Grid of clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHucn.png)

This button sends me to a separate screen that is related directly with the selected client, when this happens, the URL is as follows:

http://sistemaprueba.com/modulos?1

where the value after the question mark represents the value of the id of the selected client. Now, I need to save the value of that id in a variable to be able to use it later, how can I do that?

This is my grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre Cliente</th>
                <th>Ingresar</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($results as $result)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$result->nombre_cliente}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route ('modulos',[$result->id])}}" class="btn-box-tool" ><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the route to the new screem:

```
Route::get('/modulos', 'HomeController@modulos')->name('modulos');
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $id = \Auth::user()->id;

        $results = DB::table('clients')->join('clients_company', 'clients_company.fk_id_client', '=', 'client.id')
            ->where('clients_company.fk_id_usuar',$id)->get();

        return view('clients',compact('results'));
    }

    public function modulos()
    {
        return view('modulos');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either change your href to "/modulos/1" and your route and controller to:

```
// route
Route::get('/modulos/{clientId}', 'HomeController@modulos')->name('modulos');

// controller
public function index($clientId)
{
  // Use $clientId
}
```

Or give a named parameter in your url, like "/modulos?clientId=1", then:

```
// route (unchanged)
Route::get('/modulos', 'HomeController@modulos')->name('modulos');

// controller
public function index()
{
  $clientId = request()->input('clientId');
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could parse the url with PHP's function parse_url() in your controller, to extract the GET part of the url for you to manipulate. Not the cleanest solution. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

The first method may be preferable for your purpose.